# Overriding button background

Tags: java, swing, overriding, jbutton

Hello I try to override settings of a normal JButton. Every setting is changing except the Background color. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Button extends JButton {

    int red = 0;
    int green = 175;
    int blue = 206;

    Color kleur = new Color(red, green, blue);

    public Button(String text) {
        super(text);

        this.setBackground(kleur);
        this.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        this.setBorder(null);
        this.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.setContentAreaFilled(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086355/how-to-set-a-backgroud-color-of-a-jbutton-in-java -- check this out

Comment: public class Button can be miss_spelled by JVM, because there is awt.Button

Comment: I changed it to CustomButton. Just to be sure I gave it a green foreground color and that seems to work.. but still no background color

Comment: I think problem with this method **setContentAreaFilled**. Watch docs [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled(boolean)]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't set the opaque to true.

```
this.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: seriously! setting content area filled to `false` then setting setOpaque to `true` would take away the actual effect like on focus change and also make the color ugly.

Comment: Obviously I changed the contentareafilled method but that was not the whole solution.

Comment: why not ? can you explain please ? At the very least, JButton's opaque is `true` by default. Your answer in parallel to your question is not making much sense to me

Comment: Well I don't know why but that did the trick.. Somehow its not default true.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `contentAreaFilled` flag  to `false` right after setting the background. `setContentAreaFilled(false)`, you are telling the button that it should not `paint` it's content area. However, if you wish to have a transparent button, such as an `icon` only button, for example, then you should set this to `false`.