# A font doesn't appear in IntelliJ's dialog of choosing a font

Tags: linux, fonts, intellij-idea, linux-mint

I installed Monaco font using this [code](https://gist.github.com/rogerleite/99819). However, it doesn't appear in `Setting -> Editor -> Color and fonts -> Font`. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install fonts in another way. Just use the [Font Viewer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gnome-font-viewer/).

[image]

I use IDEA under ElementaryOS and it works for me.

#### Update:

[image]

Comment: font viewer says monaco is installed.

Comment: @Alex In `Setting -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> Font` option `Show only monospaced fonts` must be disable. See updates.

Comment: A font doesn't appear in IntelliJ's dialog of choosing a font! Is that not clear?

Comment: @Alex [Try to find another version of the TTF file](http://askubuntu.com/a/22487/181228).

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a folder `monaco` in directory `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`

and copy the font 'monaco.ttf' into this folder.

Then, run `fc-cache -v -f`

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problems recently. The reason IDEA could not find the font might be the installing location of the fonts not correct.

At the beginning, my font was put under `~/.fonts`, the font name not show in IDEA settings. Then I put a copy of the font to `.local/share/fonts`, and with command `fc-cache -v -f` to refresh the cache, the font name can be selected in IDEA font settings.

Hope it would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ settings you can change only Editor Pane's font. But you can set any font available in your system to any IntelliJ UI component.If you want to be in control of entire IDE (Project tree, Menu Bar, Labels, etc) create simple plugin with this line of code in it: `UIManager.put("XXX.font", new Font("fontName", style, size))`
where XXX is name of UI component like Label, TextField, Tree, etc.). Full list of Swing components (IntelliJ built using Swing framework) you can find here: [List of Java Swing UI properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951558/list-of-java-swing-ui-properties)   After executing plugin all new font settings will be applied to IntelliJ's UI. Here is the code sample:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.wm.ToolWindow;
import com.intellij.openapi.wm.ToolWindowFactory;
import com.intellij.ui.content.Content;
import com.intellij.ui.content.ContentFactory;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyUIPlugin implements ToolWindowFactory
{

    private ToolWindow myToolWindow;

    public static final String TOOL_WINDOW_ID = "MyUISettings";

    public MyUIPlugin() {}

    // Create the tool window content.
    public void createToolWindowContent(final Project project, final ToolWindow toolWindow) {
        myToolWindow = toolWindow;
        this.createContent(toolWindow);
}

public void createContent(final ToolWindow toolWindow) {
    final ContentFactory contentFactory = toolWindow.getContentManager().getFactory();
    JLabel myPluginUI = new JLabel("This is empty panel with my custom fonts settings behind it");
    final Content content = contentFactory.createContent(myPluginUI, "", true);
    toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(content);
    UIManager.put("TextField.font", new Font(...));
    UIManager.put("List.font", new Font(...));
    UIManager.put("Label.font", new Font(...));
    UIManager.put("Button.font", new Font(...));
    .....
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myPluginUI);
}
```

}

Additionally you even can write small Swing code instead of `JLabel`        placeholder, with list of UI elements and list of all fonts available in the system by calling `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts()`. And you can assign different font to different component types right in your plugin window  and have full customization of IntelliJ UI fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by following the instructions and installing it from this repo: https://github.com/probil/Monaco-IDE-font.