# Java swing close icon

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I would like to create a close button. For this, I need a `close` icon, which I would like to get from the current UI style. I've found a function for this: `UIManager.getIcon(key)`

The only problem is, that I don't know any key. I have no idea, how to get a `close` icon.

Comment: What does `UIManager.getIcon("close")` return? Or did you try anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet (is actually a fully functional class) to print all the UIManager key, or to filter them based on a keyword. In your case you want to check all the keys containing (ignore case for more results) a "close" string.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printUIManagerKeys("close");
  }

  private static void printUIManagerKeys(String filter) {

    String filterToLowerCase = filter.toLowerCase();

    Enumeration<?> keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();

    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {

      Object key = keys.nextElement();
      String keyToString = key.toString().toLowerCase();

      if (filter != null && keyToString.contains(filterToLowerCase)) {
        System.out.println(key + " ( " + UIManager.getDefaults().get(key) + " )");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output on the console:

> InternalFrameTitlePane.closeButtonOpacity ( true )
>   PopupMenu.consumeEventOnClose ( false )
>   InternalFrame.paletteCloseIcon ( javax.swing.plaf.metal.OceanTheme$IFIcon@1fcb1a )
>   InternalFrame.closeSound ( sounds/FrameClose.wav )
>   InternalFrame.closeIcon ( javax.swing.plaf.metal.OceanTheme$IFIcon@100d6ea )
>   Tree.closedIcon ( sun.swing.ImageIconUIResource@1cc678a )

So next step is to get and see how the icon with the key `InternalFrame.closeIcon` looks.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an exhausting list of keys:

http://thebadprogrammer.com/swing-uimanager-keys/

What you're looking for is `"InternalFrame.closeIcon"`.

Also here is the list included along with official (Oracle) links to the resource keys:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25740576/1705598

Answer (score 1):

> The only problem is, that I don't know any key

Check out [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for code that displays all the UI properties in a GUI. The GUI displays the actual Icon so you can easily choose the Icon you want to use.