# Java Swing UIManager Key

Tags: java, swing, uimanager

I'm learning Swing for the first time and I'm trying to change the colors of individual components using

```
UIManager.put("key", value),
```

but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to change the color of specific components because I don't know exactly what they are called, namely the bar where the title and the close button is located. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is a fairly complete list of keys in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951558/list-of-java-swing-ui-properties).

Comment: @StevenWolfe Yeah I read this post, my problem is that I can't figure out which one corresponds to the title bar. Seemingly none do.

Comment: If you're using a JFrame then it appears it can be modified using the code in the second answer [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482971/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-titlebar-in-jframe).

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows a particular problem that you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

To have an idea of what can be changed in the current Look and Feel, you can try:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().entrySet().stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
    return o1.getKey().toString().compareTo(o2.getKey().toString());
}).forEach(entry -> {
    System.out.print(entry.getKey());
    System.out.print(" ---> ");
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
});
```