# How to listen default color change inside my custom JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, colors, themes

I am the author of some `JComponent` extension. I wrote some example components.

In one example components I am just populating them with predefined subcomponents:

```
public class JSwingExample02 extends JComponent {

    public JSwingExample02() {
        populate();
    }

    private void populate() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("Hello World!");
        add(jLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

in other components I am drawing them from scratch

```
@Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2.fillOval(10, 10, 100, 100);
}
```

Now my components are used from withing third party code (IDEA Plugin) and it applies color theme for it: my components are shown in "dark theme" although I have no any line of code for color.

For example

[image]

i.e. text is white.

How can I LISTEN to these colors, i.e. know them beforehand, if I want for example, to draw something explicit with them?

Comment: Implement a custom listener and have these components register listeners. Override the relevant methods (for example `setBackground(Color bg)`) to fire those listener.

Comment: What to listen?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your question. You mean which methods should be listened to ?

Comment: Try to get the LAF of the custom component by `UIManager.getLookAndFeel();` You can also listen to changes in LAF by `UIManager.addPropertyChangeListener`

Comment: Which property to listen in `UIManager`?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to get and set colors.  Here are a few. This creates a simple frame/panel combination to show the background color. You can also set the color in the `paintComponent` method.  There it will be foreground or background depending on what you are painting.

A nice way to offer the user to select color is the `JColorChooser`.  It can accept a default color and return whatever is selected.

If you really want to know when a color has changed you need to establish a listener for the component  and listen for property changes.  The example shows the `demo` panel listening for foreground and background color changes.  Each of your components must register a property listeners to handle events.

**NOTE:** The Demo class is actually listening for its own changes. This does not have to be the case. Any class that implements the `PropertyChangeListener` interface may listen for property change events from any other class that fires property changes.  Just make certain that particular class instance is used when registering events.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorDemo extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ColorDemo demo = new ColorDemo();           
        demo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        // listen for these properties
        demo.addPropertyChangeListener("background", demo );
        demo.addPropertyChangeListener("foreground", demo );
        
        frame.add(demo);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        
        demo.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        System.out.println(
                "back ground color is : " + demo.getBackground());
        demo.setVisible(true);
        // use color chooser
        Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,
                "Color Chooser", demo.getBackground());
        System.out.println(
                "Retrieved new color from chooser " + newColor);
        System.out.println(
                "default foreground color is :" + demo.getForeground());
        
        demo.setForeground(Color.RED);
        demo.repaint();
    }
        
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println(
                    "Graphics context color : " + g.getColor());
        }
    
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
        String name = pce.getPropertyName();
        System.out.println(name + " change caught");
        System.out.println("old " + name + " was " + pce.getOldValue());
        System.out.println("new " + name + " is " + pce.getNewValue());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, but I listened for background and foreground properties -- listeners are never called.

Comment: You never said that in your question.  But if you're subclassing JComponent then you should receive property changes if you registered them.    If you replace the JPanel with JComponent my example will still work. I recommend you provide a [mre] .

Comment: Did you look at my example to see if you did the same things?  Also, if your components are completely build from scratch (i.e. no API subclassing of AWT classes) then you would need to fire your own events within each property you want to have listened too.

Comment: Your example works because you extended `JPanel`. It is a property of `JPanel` that it reflects background setting. I have extended `JComponent` and it still works. Not me is setting the colors, the caller does. And somehow it appears both in `Graphics` and in other props.

Comment: The question is: what is a STANDARD way to set colors/theme of a component, that component author should rely on. I can't claim thirparty to call `setBackground`, I need to accommodate what thirparty does.

Comment: There is no standard way.  It depends on what the author decided to use and then to document that in the API.   If you're making Java components and third parties want to use them then they should use the methods described in the `JComponent` API.   But perhaps you are thinking of Java Beans where there are certain requirements to getters and setters and their property descriptions.  [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html) may help answer your  question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set LAF and listen to LAF changes:

```
class JSwingExample02 extends JComponent  {

    public JSwingExample02(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        //set LAF
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //listen to LAF changes
        UIManager.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        populate();
    }

    private void populate() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("Hello World!");
        add(jLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    //returns active LAF
    public LookAndFeel lookAndFeel(){
        return UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
    }
}
```

"lookAndFeel" property change is fired when LAF changes.
See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951558/list-of-java-swing-ui-properties) for a list of other properties.